# How to avoid creating new ObjectMapper instance each type response from external system is received and parsed with Jackson?

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, jackson

I'm developing an application which calls the REST API of external system and maps the response using Jackson. The DTO looks as follows:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class FetchEmployeeLeavesResponse {
    lateinit var leaves: List<EmployeeLeaveType>

    @JsonProperty("response")
    fun unpackNested(response: Map<String, Any>) {
        val employeeLeaves = JSONArray()
        if (response["result"] is List<*>) {
            employeeLeaves.addAll(response["result"] as List<*>)
            val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
            mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            leaves = mapper.readValue(employeeLeaves.toJSONString())
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid creating `JavaTimeModule` and `ObjectMapper` instance each time I'm parsing the response? I can't autowire any bean here since this object is a DTO and I don't have an access to Spring context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pull it out to the top level:

```
private val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().also { it.registerModule(JavaTimeModule()) }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class FetchEmployeeLeavesResponse { ... }
```

This way the mapper is created once when the class is loaded and

> [ALL configuration of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)

as required in documentation.

Or even make a separate file declaring a top-level `val mapper` and import it in other files if you have a fixed list of modules you want to use everywhere.

Comment: Genial! Thanks a lot!